# Can't plot smooth spline in R

Tags: r, plot, spline

I am trying to use a smoothing spline on my dataset. I use smooth.spline function. And want to plot my fit next. However, for some reason it won't plot my model. It doesn't even give any error. I only get a error message after running smooth.spline function that 'cross-validation with non-unique 'x' values seems doubtful'. But I don't think it shouldn't make too much of a difference to the practical result.

My code is:

```
library('splines')


fit_spline <- smooth.spline(data.train$age,data.train$effect,cv = TRUE)


plot(data$effect,data$age,col="grey")
lines(fit_spline,lwd=2,col="purple")



legend("topright",("Smoothing Splines with 5.048163 df selected by CV"),col="purple",lwd=2)
```

What I get is:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

Number 1. If you do `smooth.spline(x, y)`, plot your data with `plot(x, y)` not `plot(y, x)`.

Number 2. Don’t pass in `data.train` for fitting then a different dataset `data` for plotting. If you want to see how the spline looks like at new data points, use `predict.smooth.spline` first. See `?predict.smooth.spline`.